# React component isn't re rendering the fetch data in unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a context with dummy child component.

**Dummy component**

```
function DefaultMockComponent() {

  const values = useContext(CurrencyContext)
  const valuesItems = Object.keys(values).map(value => {
    if (typeof values[value] === 'function') {
      return <div key={value} data-testid={value}>{value + '()'}</div>
    } else {
      return <div key={value} data-testid={value}>{values[value]}</div>
    }
  })

  return(
    <>
      {valuesItems}
    </>
  )
}
```

**Context unit test**

```
  // This test don't re render with the new data from fetch
  it('should pass the correct values', async () => {

    // This mock FAILS (see edit 2)
    fetch
      .mockResponse(req => {
        if (/.*\/ticker\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
          return new Promise(() => ({ body: JSON.stringify(tickerResponse) }))

        } else if (/.*\/day-summary\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
          return new Promise(() => ({ body: JSON.stringify(summaryResponse) }))

        }
      })

    render(
      <CurrencyProvider>
        <DefaultMockComponent />
      </CurrencyProvider>
    )

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('currency').textContent).toBe("btc"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('volBRL').textContent).toBe("41198719.10154287"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('closing').textContent).toBe("326900.00666999"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('sell').textContent).toBe("360000.00000000"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('buy').textContent).toBe("359999.99006000"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('last').textContent).toBe("359999.99006000"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('vol').textContent).toBe("259.88030295"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('low').textContent).toBe("353684.14000000"))
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId('high').textContent).toBe("380000.00000000"))
  });
```

**Here fetch is mocked**. I'm reading the MockComponent information and comparing it with the response object information. My problem is that the MockComponent renders only with the default context state values, as you can see:

**Rendered MockComponent**

```html
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          data-testid="high"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="low"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="vol"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="last"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="buy"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="sell"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="closing"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="volBRL"
        >
          0
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="currency"
        >
          btc
        </div>
        <div
          data-testid="setCurrency"
        >
          setCurrency()
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Which is strange since **my Cypress E2E test works fine**. How can I make the DefaultMockComponent to render the data returned from fetch?

**EDIT 1**

**CurrencyProvider of CurrencyContext**

```
export default function CurrencyProvider({children}) {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('btc')
  const [high, setHigh] = useState('0')
  const [low, setLow] = useState('0')
  const [vol, setVol] = useState('0')
  const [last, setLast] = useState('0')
  const [buy, setBuy] = useState('0')
  const [sell, setSell] = useState('0')
  const [closing, setClosing] = useState('0')
  const [volBRL, setVolBRL] = useState('0')

  useEffect(update, [currency])

  function update() {
    const ticker = `https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/${currency}/ticker/`

    fetch(ticker)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setHigh(data.ticker.high)
        setLow(data.ticker.low)
        setVol(data.ticker.vol)
        setLast(data.ticker.last)
        setBuy(data.ticker.buy)
        setSell(data.ticker.sell)
      })

    const date = new Date()
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)

    const year = date.getFullYear()
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1
    const day = date.getDate()

    const summary = `https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/${currency}/day-summary/${year}/${month}/${day}/`

    fetch(summary)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setClosing(data.closing)
        setVolBRL(data.volume)
      })
  }

  return(
    <CurrencyContext.Provider value={{
      high,
      low,
      vol,
      last,
      buy,
      sell,
      closing,
      volBRL,
      currency,
      setCurrency
    }}>
      {children}
    </CurrencyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to [lissettdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14349808/lissettdm). Now the fetch function isn't failing, but the values still not being updated plus I'm getting "*An update to CurrencyProvider inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)*" warning. Following the mock code that works:

**Mock without jest-fetch-mock (as lissettdm answer)**

```js
    const fetchSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "fetch").mockImplementation((req) =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => {
          if (/.*\/ticker\/.*/.test(req)) {
            return tickerResponse
          } else if (/.*\/day-summary\/.*/.test(req)) {
            return summaryResponse
          }
        },
      })
    );
```

**Mock with jest-fetch-mock**

```js
fetch
      .mockResponse(req => {
        if (/.*\/ticker\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
          return Promise.resolve({ body: JSON.stringify(tickerResponse) })

        } else if (/.*\/day-summary\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
          return Promise.resolve({ body: JSON.stringify(summaryResponse) })

        }
      })
```

Comment: Don't fully understand your code but seems to me that you never change anything in CurrencyContext, u only call values.  If there is no change to any state, it would not cause a rerender.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JoseRodrigues. I'll edit the question to include my context, since the state is changed there. It's strange to me that the same code works on visual test and at the unit test it fails.

Comment: should `useEffect(update, [currency])` go after the actual update function?

Comment: Since I've declared update with function keyword, it doesn't matter when I use it. I've made the change just to check and it failed. Thank you.

Comment: do the comments in https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock/issues/165 help ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli what's the connection between my question and this issue?

Comment: If your mock is not working correctly, it will not run the `setXX` commands and will not alter context.

Comment: I got it @GabrielePetrioli. Sorry for my poor english. Going to try the issue solutions in a minute.

Comment: I tried to substitute fetch with fetchMock as in issue (substituted it with FetchMock too), but I got undefined for it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem:

You see only the default context values because the fetch function is failing. The first `then` expect that the response object contains `json` function and that part is missing.

#### Solution:

You need to add `json` function to your mock implementation :

```
const fetchSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "fetch").mockImplementationOnce((req) =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => {
     if (/.*\/ticker\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
        return new Promise(() => ({ body: JSON.stringify(tickerResponse) }))
     } else if (/.*\/day-summary\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
        return new Promise(() => ({ body: JSON.stringify(summaryResponse) }))
     }
   },
 }));
 //--> check if fetch was called
 expect(fetchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**About this warning:**

> An update to CurrencyProvider inside a test was not wrapped in
> act(...)" warning

Probably, your testing is ending without the state be flushed. I think you should use `findBy` methods which are a combination of `getBy` queries and `waitFor`

```
 const currency = await screen.getByTestId('currency');
 expect(currency.textContent).toBe("btc");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. There's a typo in "fetch". Check my edit 2 in the question, please.

Comment: What lib are you using for testing?

Comment: I'm currently using create-react-app with jest and @testing-library/react.

Comment: That's it. At first the fetch mock was failing, then the test was terminating early. Thanks for your help.